# Cache content of Ajax Get call in varnish 5.2

Tags: ajax, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am new in varnish and using Varnish 5.2 and want to know why Varnish do not cache AJAX Get request while it does cache the content if same Ajax call is requested through a URL call from browser.

Following is the default.vcl file

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}


sub vcl_recv {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Remove the proxy header (see https://httpoxy.org/#mitigate-varnish)
    unset req.http.proxy;

    # Normalize the query arguments
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    # Allow purging
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
      # If you got this stage (and didn't error out above), purge the cached result
      return (purge);
    }

    # Some generic cookie manipulation, useful for all templates that follow
    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove DoubleClick offensive cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gads=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the AddThis cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
      unset req.http.cookie;
    }


    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
      return (hash);
    }
    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
      return (hash);
    }


    if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest"){
        return (hash);
    }
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";

    return (hash);
}


sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 1200s;
    set beresp.ttl = 120s;

    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0")
      { unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control; // for Varnish >= 3.0 set beresp.do_esi = true; // for Varnish < 3.0 // esi;
      }
}
```

Following is the response of varnishlog command file

```
*   << Request  >> 98313     
-   Begin          req 98311 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1523473475.288141 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1523473475.288141 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       192.168.33.1 39288
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /get-test/sf1102505aabc133ddbae?customerId=110250
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: test-website.test
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Referer: http://test-website.test/get-widget-110250-ProductID1
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: PHPSESSID=e41a91kihnchjn9c4aor07jl3p
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.33.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       Host: test-website.test
-   ReqHeader      Host: test-website.test
-   ReqURL         /get-test/sf1102505aabc133ddbae?customerId=110250
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: PHPSESSID=e41a91kihnchjn9c4aor07jl3p
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: PHPSESSID=e41a91kihnchjn9c4aor07jl3p
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: PHPSESSID=e41a91kihnchjn9c4aor07jl3p
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: 
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: 
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 98314 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1523473475.452031 0.163890 0.163890
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 19:04:35 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Debug: 1
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     X-Debug-Token: 4dda3e
-   RespHeader     X-Debug-Token-Link: http://test-website.test/_profiler/4dda3e
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 2039
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98313
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1523473475.452071 0.163930 0.000039
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1523473475.452225 0.164084 0.000155
-   ReqAcct        589 0 589 527 2039 2566
-   End
```

**Remember: It gets a HIT if call directly from browser**

Answer (score 0):

do you have a `varnishlog`  of the normal `GET`  request - aka from the browser

i suspect that the xmlhttprequest - sends:

```
-   ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache
```

you either remove the 2 headers in `vcl_recv` by unsetting them:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Pragma;
    unset req.http.Cache-Control;
}
```

or you disable it in the application itself. for example if you are using jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

but depends on how you do the ajax requests.